# how to specify bootstrap version on laravel/ui package?

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5, laravel-10, laravel-ui

i am trying to using bootstrap on my laravel project using the laravel/ui package

https://github.com/laravel/ui

i am following the installation instruction

`composer require laravel/ui`
and  choose the
`php artisan ui bootstrap`
to use the bootstrap

by default it install bootstrap 5 but i need the version 4 for the adminlte3 theme

is there a way to specify which bootstrap version that i can use ?

since i'm want to use the version 4 of it not 5

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option. The bootstrap version to be installed is hardcoded in the `Laravel\Ui\Presets\Bootstrap` class.

These are the packages that get added to your `package.json` dependencies with [Laravel UI 4](https://github.com/laravel/ui/blob/4.x/src/Presets/Bootstrap.php).

```
'bootstrap' => '^5.2.3',
'@popperjs/core' => '^2.11.6',
'sass' => '^1.56.1',
```

Simply change them with the ones that were added with [Laravel UI 2](https://github.com/laravel/ui/blob/2.x/src/Presets/Bootstrap.php), the last major version to use Bootstrap 4. I ignore if sass-loader is strictly needed.

```
'bootstrap' => '^4.0.0',
'jquery' => '^3.2',
'popper.js' => '^1.12',
'sass' => '^1.15.2',
'sass-loader' => '^8.0.0',
```

You'll also need to manually copy some stubs over to your project.

- https://github.com/laravel/ui/tree/2.x/src/Presets/bootstrap-stubs
- https://github.com/laravel/ui/tree/2.x/src/Auth/bootstrap-stubs